# reading char types from a string and assigning their numeric value to an int type struct member

Tags: c

I am working on the header file of an audio file in `C`.

While trying to extract the values chunk by chunk 
and assign to members of a struct (which are the
attributes of the header file in different data type)
 I faced a problem of not getting the values but the
 address of the data. It works for char types but not for int types. I have tried `sscanf`, `atoi`, and type casting. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Maybe I am missing a silly thing. My code roughly seems as follow as:

```
struct wav_header {
               char chunkID[4];
               int chunkSize;}sound_header;

enum {SUCCESS, FAIL};

void writeToStruct(FILE *wavin);

main(void){          
FILE *wptr1;
int ret = SUCCESS; 
char wavContent1[]="sound.wav";// this is the sound wave i am extracting

if ((wptr1 = fopen(wavContent1, "r")) == NULL){
      printf("Cannot open");
      ret = FAIL;
       }
else {      
  writeToStruct(wptr1);
  fclose(wptr1);
      }   
return ret;
}

void writeToStruct(FILE *wavin){
  int i=0,chunkByte[]={4,4,4,4,4,2,2,4,4,2,2,4,4};
  char buff[5];
  long offset=0;

 while (!feof(wavin)&& offset<44){                
     int num = fread(buff, sizeof(char), chunkByte[i], wavin);
     buff[num * sizeof(char)] = '\0'; 

     switch(i){
       case 0:strncpy(sound_header.chunkID,buff,chunkByte[i]);
              printf("chunkID--- %s\n",&sound_header.chunkID);
              break;
       case 1:strncpy(temp,buff,chunkByte[i]); 
              sscanf(temp,"%x",x);
              sound_header.chunkSize=x;     
              printf("\nchunkSize --- %x\n",sound_header.chunkSize);
              break;           
       default: printf("error: out of range");
           } 
 offset=offset+chunkByte[i++];
   }
 }
```

(case `0` works correctly as i am assigning a `char` type from buffer `buff` to a `char` type member of the `struct`)

(case `1` doesn't type from the work as I am trying to assign the `char` temporary buffer to an `int` type `struct` member ). `sscanf()` and `atoi()` say to be deprecated. Can somebody help me giving insight?

it just returns null while it should have returned `B4B320`.
Also note: `chunkbyte[]` is my size specifier array.

Comment: Use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy` - you are not copying a string but a binary int. Or use `sound_header.chunkSize= (int)buff;`

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie thanks but I had tried :sound_header.chunkSize= (int)buff; which just returns the address of the memory location, not the content of the data

Comment: @MichaelWalz i just joined Stackoverflow few minutes ago. i didn't get what you mean. i can post the full code if it helps. the doted line is to indicate irrelevant part is missing there

Comment: Be creative and think:if it returns the address then you must dereference it.I lLeave that to you as excercise.

Comment: Oh god, I just reformatted your code and you edited again

Comment: Please reformat your code with proper indentation, there isn't any empty line or tabulation to keep the code readable.

No one likes to read a code like this, and most likely won't help at all

Comment: @Josh formatting your code is not related to stackoverflow, it's related to programming. Look at the code in your C textbook; this code is formatted. Then look at _your_ code. You see the difference ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz and Zorgatone thanks. i hope it is better now.i thought aligning all at 4 spaces is the requirement. Am trying while waiting for any suggestion. Mr.Paul, i had tried your suggestion.it didn't work.the thing is i dont have detailed knowledge on the behaviors of the c functions to manipulate disk file

Comment: @Josh your formatting is still terrible, but at least there is an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

the case for assigning to integer struct member can be fixed  by declaring a new pointer, int *temp, and using memcpy() as follows
    case 1:temp=&sound_header.chunkSize;
           memcpy(temp,buff,chunkByte[i]);
           printf("chunkSize---%x\n",sound_header.chunkSize);
           break;
This further needs to correct the endianess as my laptop has a little endian architecture, it gives in reverse order of two byte numbers.which also doesn't keep the null values